# CSS min-height calc() dynamic property in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, dynamic-css

I have some very basic HTML & CSS, and I'd like to have the "sticky footer" effect.  This is for an application internal to my company, so we can enforce latest browsers only (IE11+).  I saw that [IE9+ supports the CSS `calc()` dynamic property](http://caniuse.com/calc), so I put it to use.

#### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h1 id="title">The Title</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Stuff....</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html,
body,
#wrap{
    height: 100%;
}
#title{
    height: 60px;
}
#content{
    min-height: 100%; /*fallback*/
    min-height: calc(100% - 60px); /*the title is 60px tall*/
}
```

---

### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4uWG/2/) | [Full Screen demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s4uWG/2/show/light/)

---

This works great in Chrome and Firefox, but IE11 (the only version I care about) *will not* re-calculate this value when the window is resized.  Sometimes it also seems to unnecessarily extend past the end of the page, thus causing scroll when it's not needed.

And I doing something wrong here, or is this an IE bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a bug, but if you too aren't afraid of jquery you can fix the bug with it

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    /* The jquery calc code */
    $('#content').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=100px');
});
```

Comment: I changed this to modify `min-height` instead of `width` and this seems to work exactly how I want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use box-sizing. Altering the following code should sort your issue. This should accomodate 91% of users including most IE11, IE10, IE9, IE8 and IE7 (If Required) users - http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing.

I would also recommend the use of classes as ID's should be unique to each element.

**CSS**

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,
body,
.wrap{
    height: 100%;
}
.title{
    height: 60px;
}
.content{
    min-height: 100%; /*fallback*/
    padding-top:60px;
}
```

Comment: I am already using `box-sizing: border-box;` in my application, I just forgot to include it in this example/demo.  It seems to not help at all :(

Comment: Sorry I'm being an idiot, I've made a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/asherstoppard/NK7sM/1/. I completely forgot to apply an absolute position to the title div. This should do it for you mate.